# Swift Must call a designated initializer of the superclass uiinputviewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uiinputviewcontroller

I get the error in the subject after this morning's upgrade to 8.3.

The code below used to work perfectly, however it doesn't compile anymore. Can any of you please help me?

```
protocol CustomAccessoryProtocol {
    func controlButtonPressed(tag:Int)
}

class CustomAccessory : UIInputViewController {
    var accessoryView : UIView!
    var delegate : CustomAccessoryProtocol!

    @IBOutlet weak var returnButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var backButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var forwardButton: UIButton!

    init(delegate: CustomAccessoryProtocol){
        super.init()
        self.delegate = delegate
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
        let customNib = UINib(nibName: "CustomAccessory", bundle: nil)
        accessoryView = customNib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
    }

    @IBAction func buttonPress(sender: AnyObject) {
        delegate.controlButtonPressed(sender.tag!)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(accessoryView)
    }
}
```

Comment: I wonder what the designated initializer for UIInputViewController?  Not `init(frame: CGRect)` I presume. ?

Comment: Isn't the first init a convenience init? Do you have to add convenience keyword to it? I don't have it down to a science. I've had some cases where I had to struggle with it for awhile to figure it out. Based on the initializers you *do* have, I assume you read the Swift [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html) on the subject at some point...

Comment: Did anything change in the 8.3 docs for UIInputViewController or UIViewController?

Comment: I can't find anything changed or maybe I'm missing something, I am also wondering about the designated initializer as all I can see are the ones that I already have. Maybe they will update the documentation as so far I cant see anything on this. Hoewever, it seems to work when adding convenience to the first init and self.init rather than super. You sir just made my day!

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem on the following code with NSWindowController:

```
init() {
    super.init()
}
```

I changed it to:

```
convenience init() {
    self.init()
}
```

I'm thinking that Apple is enforcing convenience inits more strictly than before.

Comment: with self.init() I get warning "Could not find an overload for 'init' that accepts the supplied arguments

Comment: Adding `convenience init()` is giving me a bad excess. Please help.

Comment: Maybe because you're referencing `self.init()`which references itself?

Comment: No. Its like recursive function call, it never works. Why its having this much upvotes?

Comment: This causes an infinite loop.