# Cannot subclass UIButton: Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'UIButton'

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

Trying to subclass UIButton but the error `Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'UIButton'` occurs.

Researching several SO posts [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29031270/initializer-does-not-override-a-designated-initializer-from-its-superclass), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27079681/how-to-init-a-uibutton-subclass), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29531133/swift-must-call-a-designated-initializer-of-the-superclass-uiinputviewcontroller), or several others did not help as those solutions didn't work.

How can we subclass `UIButton` in Swift and define a custom init function?

```
import UIKit

class KeyboardButton : UIButton {
    var letter = ""
    var viewController:CustomViewController?

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    init(letter: String, viewController: CustomViewController) {
        super.init()
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: As the error says you can't call `super.init()` as that isn't a designated initialiser. You will need to call `super.init(frame:frame)`, which means you will need to supply a frame to your initialiser.  Having said that, this looks pretty awful. You should probably implement a delegate pattern rather than supplying a view controller to the initialiser

Comment: Good point @Paulw11 thanks for the suggestion. New to Swift so the suggestion is most appreciated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have to call the superclass' designated initializer:

**Swift 3 & 4:**

```
init(letter: String, viewController: CustomViewController) {
    super.init(frame: .zero)
}
```

**Swift 1 & 2:**

```
init(letter: String, viewController: CustomViewController) {
    super.init(frame: CGRectZero)
}
```

As [Paulw11](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3418066/paulw11) says in the comments, a view generally shouldn't have a reference to its controller, except as a weak reference using the delegate pattern, which would promote reusability.

Comment: Thanks! New to Swift, so the delegate pattern is a great suggestion. Seems hackish to use `CGRectZero` as the initial frame only to change it later. There is no way to use the initializer with no parameters? Thanks for your help!

Comment: The designated initializer has one non-optional parameter, so there is no way to call it without parameters. If it makes you feel better, `init()` is just a convenience initializer that calls `init(frame: CGRectZero)` anyway.

Comment: But how do you set the button type in the subclass?

Comment: @TodCunningham You can't do it in exactly the same way due to Swift's strict type safety. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/24014122/1445366 for some other approaches.