# Subclass of UIButton cant call the buttonType initializer

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, initialization, uikit

I am trying to subclass a `UIButton` so that its default initilizer sets it up the same way it would if you called `UIButton(type: UIButtonType.roundedRect)`. However, I am unable to due to some Swift restrictions saying that that is not a designated initilizer. Additionally the `buttonType` property is read only.

How can I do this in Swift?

For reference this code does not compile because I do not call a designated initializer.

```
class ToggleButton : UIButton {
    init() {
        super.init(type: UIButtonType.roundedRect)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("TROUBLE")
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to implement your custom init() methods, then compulsory you have to use designated initializer.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32343198/cannot-subclass-uibutton-must-call-a-designated-initializer-of-the-superclass

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swift can be a little annoying with the initializers. This should do it for you.

```
class ToggleButton : UIButton {
    convenience init() {
        self.init(type: .roundedRect)
    }
    
    convenience init(type buttonType: UIButtonType) {
        self.init(type: buttonType)
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("TROUBLE")
    }
}
```

EDIT: Feb 12, 21

As of Swift 5, this can be accomplished with the following.

```
class ToggleButton: UIButton {
    convenience init() {
        self.init(type: .roundedRect)
    }
}
```

Comment: How to call `convenience init(type buttonType: UIButtonType)` if i have an outlet of type `ToggleButton`?

Comment: This doesn't work. It'll create an infinite loop