# Reuse and change init

Tags: swift, initialization

I'm using a custom class of AlertController 
Here I have an init

```
Self.init(message: "test1")
```

Then in the some condition, I have to change the alert message.

```
If someCondition {
 //here
}
```

I can call another `time Self.init(message: "test2")`, but it's not a good way, could anyone recommend a good way to do that?

Thanks

Comment: Don't do an init, but just set that property as a `var`, not a `let`, and do `thatObject.message = "newValue"`?

Comment: What do you mean by "a custom class of AlertController?" Is this a subclass of `UIAlertController`? (That class is specifically not intended to be subclassed. "The UIAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing.")

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the message property after initialisation:

```swift
class Alert: UIAlertController {

}

let alert = Alert(title: "Title", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
alert.message = "Message"
```

Comment: In my case, I am already in the Alert class. I can do it, but the message in the init wont'e be changaed

Comment: Try this one - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33092628/how-can-i-override-convenience-init-in-uialertcontroller-for-swift